# hadoop namenode and datanote not started

Tags: hadoop

Last Edit

I fixed it by mixing many different answers together.
First I changed the rights of:

```
    /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
    /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
```

to 777.
Then I ran stop-all.sh and restarted hadoop.

Should this question be closed?

I know this has been used before, but the questioneers seem to work with much older versions. also, none of the answers helped me.

I installed hadoop 2.7.0 on Ubuntu 15.10 and followed the following tutorial exactly: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10

I tried about 20 others, this was the first that was understandable.

now, when I run jps, I get:

```
          14812 SecondaryNameNode
          15101 NodeManager
          14969 ResourceManager
          15519 Jps
```

Which means the NameNode and the DataNode have not started.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:

I think this might be important: When I formatted my namenode using

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

I got one hell of an output:

```
> Blockquote STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = me-Aspire-E5-574G/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.2
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.2-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.2.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b165c4fe8a74265c792ce23f546c64604acf0e41; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2016-01-26T00:08Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_101
************************************************************/
16/06/16 10:18:13 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/06/16 10:18:13 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
16/06/16 10:18:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Formatting using clusterid: CID-19779c07-66da-44f2-b05c-6664e2a2abfc
16/06/16 10:18:14 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
16/06/16 10:18:14 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2016 Jun 16 10:18:15
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             =me (auth:SIMPLE)
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-1368358985-127.0.1.1-1466065095377
16/06/16 10:18:15 WARN namenode.NameNode: Encountered exception during format: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
16/06/16 10:18:15 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
16/06/16 10:18:15 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at me-Aspire-E5-574G/127.0.1.1
> Blockquote
```

I did what a user in the comments advised:

When I do:

```
   hdfs namenode -format
```

I get the above long output.

However, when I do

```
  sudo hdfs namenode -format
```

I get:

```
  sudo: hdfs: command not found
```

Does that even make sense?

Comment: Did it started on other node? What does the datanode log says?

Comment: where can I find the datanode log? in

Comment: It is not in /usr/local/hadoop/logs

Comment: try adding `sudo` before the command.

Comment: before the formating you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
1 Clear the tmp folder which you set in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
2 format the namnode and datanode
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop datanode -format
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs datanode -format
3 Then start hadoop
```

Comment: fixed it 5 minutes ago in a different way, was just going to edit. Could you tell me what your solution actually does?

Comment: This steps are used to clear the namenode and datanodes 
after clearing just restart the hadoop in a fresh setup